# Codewars Twosum ARRay inequality

Tags: python, arrays, variables, indexing

I'm trying to take an array, target value, and return the index of the two elements that equate to said target value.

My code is the following;

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    #takes an array, and a target value
    #return sum of two elements that equate to target value

    for i in numbers:
        for z in numbers:
            if sum([i] + [z]) == target and numbers.index(i) != numbers.index(z):
                x = numbers.index(i)
                y = numbers.index(z)
                return [x, y]

print(two_sum([1,2,3], 4))
```

I am getting the correct outputs for the first two of the following tests, but the third one keeps returning none. I believe it's to do with the index equality statement but I really have no idea why it keeps returning the way it does. I'm quite new with coding so any advice is appreciated. Thanks

```
test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([1,2,3], 4)), [0,2])
test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([1234,5678,9012], 14690)), [1,2])
test.assert_equals(sorted(two_sum([2,2,3], 4)), [0,1])
```

Tried rearranging equality statement, rewriting code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed with the index equality condition. For the input [2,2,3] and target 4, you'll at a certain moment have `i` and `z` both equal to 2, and so their sum is the target. But then `[2,2,3].index(i)` and `[2,2,3].index(z)` are obviously equal, because they both find the value 2 at index 0 in the list.

NB: Not the problem, but `sum([i] + [z])` is an overly complex way to do `i + z`.

The solution is to iterate with *indices* instead of values. For instance:

```
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for z in range(len(numbers)):
            if numbers[i] + numbers[z] == target and i != z:
                return [i, z]
```

This will solve your issue is but is far from being an efficient solution. It has a time complexity of O(²).

It is better to create a set of the numbers first. Then visit the values in the list and see if the additional value -- that is needed for reaching the target -- is in the set. If so, you can retrieve the index of that additional value and require that it is a different index.

Here is how that could be done:

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    uniques = set(numbers)
    
    for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
        if target - val in uniques:  # the complementing value is in the set
            try:  # find its index and return both indices
                return [i, numbers.index(target - val, i + 1)]
            except:
                # This happens when target = val + val and 
                #   val only occurs once in the list
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response! I appreciate the detailed response and will push to myself to try and understand your breakdown, lol.

Comment: Just to clarify though, for your response "The problem is indeed with the index equality condition. For the input [2,2,3] and target 4, you'll at a certain moment have i and z both equal to 2, and so their sum is the target. But then [2,2,3].index(i) and [2,2,3].index(z) are obviously equal, because they both find the value 2 at index 0 in the list."......... at this point., it would be element 0,0 summing for the target value, but with the equality statement, this wouldn't pass. Shouldn't my code just keep running until conditions are met? i.e. why isn't 0, 1 being returned with the loop?

Comment: That will not happen: 1 can never be the result of an `.index(2)` call, since it will find that 2 at index 0. Even though it might be the *second* 2 your loop is iterating, a 2 is just ... a 2, so the result will be the same when you call `.index(2)`.